# Increasing resolution in AnatomicalData

Tags: curated-data, anatomy

In version 10.3 one can get an image of an anatomical structure, such as a brain, using this code:

```
AnatomyData[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Brain"], "Image"]
```

[image]

Is there any way to increase the resolution of this image?  I've tried obvious methods such as `PlotPoints`, `ImageSize` and such, but none work.  The only approach that seems to work is to retrieve a full 3D model:

```
AnatomyData[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Brain"], "Graphics3D"]
```

But that stores far more information than I need.

I can try exporting the 3D image as 2D, but the ideal solution would be to work entirely in 2D and just get a higher-resolution image.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should be able to make an image from the Graphics3D using `Export`. There you can set the file type, size, resolution and so on.

Comment: From 3D to 2D also try `Image["3D plot", ImageResolution -> 500]`?